# What's the difference between INS_AddInstrumentFunction and INS_InsertCall in Intel PIN

Tags: instruments, intel-pin

I get confused about the two functions, I want to find out when the function passed though INS_AddInstrumentFunction will be invoked, and when the ones passed though INS_InsertCall will be invoked.

I've look though the official manual of Intel PIN but didn't find the answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: [PIN: Instrumentation API](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98547/Pin/html/group__INS__INSTRUMENTATION.html)

- INS_AddInstrumentFunction: "Add a function used to instrument at instruction granularity"
- INS_InsertCall: "Insert a call to funptr relative to instruction ins."

In short, the callback argument of INS_AddInstrumentFunction gets called **once** for every instruction, when it is loaded by PIN.

The callback argument of INS_InsertCall gets called everytime that instruction is **executed**.

Comment: got it, thank you so much.